# Maven Site Staging from multiple POM in Several Modules

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, maven-site-plugin

I have a project with 5 modules with sub-projects.

```
Project
   - Module1
        -pom.xml
        --sub-proj1
            -pom.xml

   - Module2
        -pom.xml
        --sub-proj2
            -pom.xml

   - Module3
        -pom.xml
        --sub-proj3
            -pom.xml

   - Module4
        -pom.xml
        --sub-proj4
            -pom.xml

   - Module5
        -pom.xml
        --sub-proj5
            -pom.xml
```

`mvn site` command creates the site directories under each module. I want to stage it inside one common directory.

```
 <site>
   <id>${project.artifactId}-site</id>
   <url>./</url>
 </site>
```

The above configuration says that the absolute path has to be provided . So when i provided absolute path , the site gets pushed to the parent project `/target/staging` .

The problem I am facing is that `index.html` and other main `.html` of parent project(Module1) is being replaced by other parent links so only the last parent project `index.html` is found in the directory where site is generated . How can I fix it / specify a proper path for the site directories ?

**Also** how can I aggregate all the reports like javadocs, corbetura etc into one primary report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try creating a parent pom (under `project` ) and when you  run the `mvn site` from there which should solve the issue.

Add this only to your `parent` pom

```
<site>
     <id>${project.artifactId}-site</id>
     <url>./</url>
</site>
```

Comment: Great, this seems to be working fine. But there is an issue. When I checkout as a maven project from the SVN, Module (1 to 5) is created in the folder. Where should I add this pom.xml so that its placed in the parent after the maven checkout.

Comment: I think this should be posted as a different question . if you think the solution works, you should accept it